# need to exclude APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug

Tags: wp-query

I have this code:

```
query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        ),                      
                    ) );
```

now I need to remove all post from this Query `APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug`

Meaning I need to show all posts except the one from this one taxonomy.

Comment: Is the term a standard WordPress `category` or `tag`, or is a custom taxonomy?

Comment: its custom taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found a solution that's working as well:

```
query_posts( array(
  'post_type'      => APP_POST_TYPE,
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'tax_query'      => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_STORE,
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => $term->slug,
      'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
  ),
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can see is to gather a list of the terms in that taxonomy, and use them with a `NOT IN` operator in your query's `tax_query`:

```php
// Get all the terms in your custom taxonomy.
$slugs = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'industry',
    'fields'   => 'slugs',
] );

$posts = query_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_STORE,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $slugs, 
        ]
    ]
] );
```

I would suggest reading up on [query_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) if you haven't already - heed the warning that it could cause confusion and trouble down the road. `get_posts` should get you the same results without the burden of overwriting the main query.

Comment: Thank you its working! However I do not need the `// Get all the terms in your custom taxonomy.
$slugs = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'industry',
    'fields'   => 'slugs',
] );` part of it. What was the reason for it? Also it fixed another problem I had. It is now only showing posts from the same category. Thats what I wanted as well. Now I need a fix to only show one post from each taxonomy `APP_TAX_STORE`.